# Dataweave date validation for Feb 30

Tags: mule, dataweave

I want to do date validation in dataweave and if the date is invalid then set to null.

Tried:

```
'2019/02/29' as Date{format: "yyyy/MM/dd"} default null
```

Which prints "2019/02/28".

When tried:

```
'2019/03/45' as Date{format: "yyyy/MM/dd"} default null
```

Gets null successfully.

Is there any workaround for Feb?

For:

```
'2019/02/29' as Date{format: "yyyy/MM/dd"} default null
```

Expecting: null
Actual: "2019/02/28"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataWeave doesn't seem to validate dates by calendar. An alternative is to create a validation function to confirm the dates will be unchanged:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun validDate(d) = if (d == d as Date {format: "yyyy/MM/dd"} as String {format: "yyyy/MM/dd"} ) d else null
---
{
    noLeap: validDate('2019/02/29'),    
    valid: validDate('2019/02/28'),
    invalid: validDate('2019/04/31')
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "noLeap": null,
  "valid": "2019/02/28",
  "invalid": null
}
```

Comment: "DataWeave doesn't seem to validate dates by calendar". That is because right now DW uses the DateTimeFormatter in SMART ResolverStyle (using smart mode will ensure that the day-of-month is from 1 to 31, converting any value beyond the last valid day-of-month to be the last valid day-of-month.)